# Glove Breach Detection

Tags: capacitance, circuit-design

I'm trying to design a circuit that would be fitted inside large plastic gloves. That when the gloves are cut the circuit produces a signal.

Currently I'm considering having a metal (probably aluminium) lining sandwiched within the gloves that would have its capacitance measured. I can do this buy simply having a tuned capcacitive touch sensor circuit kind of like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TtDgk6WR6_I). So basically the circuit would produce high when the cut occurs. Though I don't know if this would produce the results I require.

Hoping for some possible suggestions on really how to detect when the plastic outer material is cut without using a processor as this will add overhead.

Comment: The last sentence about "without using a processor" makes the question smell wrong.  You should also mention what are you going to do when you detect a breach?  What are you ultimately trying to accomplish?  Other than that, this is a curious design challenge.

Comment: I think I know what he's trying to do.  Most likely he's building this for Fire Dept/other First Responders.  They are required to change gloves if they get cut.  All he wants is a logic high when there's a cut detected.  He'll worry about the UI.

Comment: Sorry so at the moment I'm thinking of just using one of [these](http://au.element14.com/atmel/at42qt1010-tshr/sensor-touch-cap-1ch-6sot-23/dp/1841593RL) chips to detect when touch occurs in a saw blade. However the circuit needs to do as little as possible since there's already 1ms delay from that chip which isn't great. As the value is going to pinged wirelessly to a processor that can deal with the data.

Comment: Errm, why does 1ms of delay matter? It's not like anybody wearing the gloves could react to or even perceive such a short delay.

Comment: I'm not sure that capacitance sensors will help. A cut to a glove is unlikely to change the capacitance by any noticeable amount - in fact putting a hand in there will affect the capacitance by orders of magnitude more.

Comment: tests for breaches in gloves (and other latex products) usually use a conductive liquid, such as saline. It's the only reliable way to detect tiny pinholes through which a germ or other small cell could pass.

Comment: Okay to make clear what im doing. The gloves will be cut by a band saw blade. I need to produce an electrical impulse the second the cut happens and so that I can do some other stuff with the signal. 

The reason I was hoping capacitance would work is because the bandsaw is grounded and coming into contact with it would cause a huge disruption in capacitance. Having the gloves tuned so that only this event would cause the circuit to trigger.

Comment: What about a pneumatic (air pressure) system? Pressurize the outer membrane, and use a pressure sensor to detect a sudden drop in pressure when there is a cut.  I'm thinking somewhat less pressure than normal shop air, would need to be low enough the gloves would still be flexible, but high enough to rapidly discharge when breached.

Comment: If you could electrically connect the gloves and the blade then you could just look for a voltage drop from the short circuit as the blade touches the inside aluminum while cutting it. not sure whether this is even a good idea or not from a safety point of view.

Comment: Can't really do that as it only has one point of contact which occurs when the blade cuts the glove

Comment: Have you seen this http://www.sawstop.com/ seems like does everything you want (only with a table saw).

Comment: @Tyler yeah that's kind of the idea but the way that works is the circuits complete you touch the saw. However I'm cutting metal and other conductive materials so the same concept can't be used. I need to design something that will be built into the glove and wirelessly transmit that there is a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered TWO layers of metal in the gloves, with a layer of insulation between?  Then any circuit that can detect a short should be able to detect cuts by metal objects, and also any situation where one metal layer on one side of the cut touches the other metal layer on the other side.  Note, however, that this may not be reliable for cuts caused by an insulating material, such as most types of broken glass.  Capacitance is no longer significant for this method.